# Cannot import binance Client

Tags: python, binance

I am trying to connect the binance API to my python project but am getting an error. I have the binance api package downloaded but when I have

```
from binance import Client
```

it is giving me the error `cannot find reference 'Client' in 'binance.py'`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any files named "binance" in the same folder and also that you have installed binance

```
pip install python-binance
```

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: yep i dont have any files named binance and i do have binance installed. do you have any idea why this wouldnt work apart from that?

Comment: I am not sure, but did you create the client after registering your account with Binance?

Comment: im not sure. what do you mean create the client?

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer says, you need to install this library

```
pip install python-binance
```

Here is the code to get your USDT balance and check if it works or not

```
from binance import Client

client = Client("api_key", "api_secret", testnet=True)
allBalance = client.futures_account_balance()
for ab in allBalance:
    if ab["asset"] == "USDT":
        print(round(float(ab["balance"]),2))
```

Hope it will help you